# Jenkins 2 pipeline displayName and buildid

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to modify the shown jenkins 2 pipeline displayname and the build id. What is the preferred way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From cloudbees: 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job

```
node {
    currentBuild.displayName = "fooName"
    currentBuild.description = "fooDescription"
}
```

Comment: it works, with this synthaxe, but....
`
stage("Build"){
    node{
        currentBuild.displayName = "fooName111"
        currentBuild.description = "fooDescription222"
    }
}
`
but it not works with this synthaxe:

Comment: but it not works with this synthaxe:

pipeline{
 agent any;
 stages{
  stage("Build"){
       steps{
  currentBuild.displayName = "fooName323"
        currentBuild.description = "fooDescription"

     
                }
        }
 }
}

Comment: And what about the build_id modification?

Comment: You want to change the buildId? Since when you change the displayname the buildId won't be visisble. What is the purpose of changes the buildId? It is possible too, but don't understand why you want to do it.

Comment: Because Jenkins, in its job folder structure uses the build number as build directory storing results artifacts,etc... 

If I change the display name, I think I will not find the assigned build folder.

Comment: I think you only can have integer values here anyway, it is possible to set a nother number but it still has to be an integer, since jenkins will call, nextBuildNumber and expect it to be incremented.